# What's the code if we want to trim the string

Tags: python

I am kind of noob in python and struck in middle of code. I want to trim my string.
For example- my string is "bangalore store 1321" and i want to trim it to "banglore"

Comment: That is not trimming. Trimming means removing spaces on the edges of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to keep the first word (which is not "trimming" though). So you do two things

1. break the string into a list of words (where "word" is something separated by spaces)
2. take the first element of that list

   ```
   words = mystring.split(' ')
   result = words[0]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

For a slicing answer:

```
def sub_string(str, start,end):
    return str[start:end]
```

You can also use `split`, by definition, this splits by spaces, if any other delimiter needed, you can identity it inside the split arguments `split(',')`

```
def split_string(str):
    return str.split()
```

This function will return an array of strings.  Choose whichever you want from this array

Comment: Hi, I have a transaction data for multiple stores across India. The store name is in like Banglore store 123, Mangalore store 121.. Delhi store 12. I need to filter each store according to their 1st word. using split for my store name column, i am getting output [Banglore, Store, 123]

Answer (score 0):

```
str="bangalore store 1321"
print(str.split(' ')[0])
```

Output

```
bangalore
```

Comment: Hi, I have a transaction data for multiple stores across India. The store name is in like Banglore store 123, Mangalore store 121.. Delhi store 12. I need to filter each store according to their 1st word.  using split for my store name column, i am getting output [Banglore, Store, 123]

Comment: @Nitin you add a new question. Mention what is the data that you have and output you require. Also update what you have tried so far.

Comment: I am sorry. That's the same question i am looking for.

Comment: @Nitin You need to access the first element from that list. So use str.split(' ')[0]

Answer (score 0):

You can use str's [partition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) method to avoid creating a list like [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

```
>>> first_word, _, _ = s.partition(' ')  # _ is a convention for a throwaway variable
>>> print(first_word)
bangalore
```

`str.partition` takes one argument - the separator - and returns the parts of the string before and after the first occurrence of the separator.